# How to adjust string to correct input type of classOf in scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, package, scala-reflect

I want to remove the following import:

```
import my.package.version.class1
```

the reason is that I want to pass the `version` as a parameter so I can have the following options:

```
my.package.version1.class1
my.package.version2.class1
my.package.version3.class1
```

When I do it hard-coded like that it works

```
classOf[my.package.version1.class1].getPackage
```

But I need it to be a String type so I can append the version each time.

```
val hh = "my.package."+versionParamater+".class1"



 classOf[hh].getPackage //THIS WONT WORK error: identifier expected but string literal found.
```

I also tried doing this and it didnt work as well:

```
 val pkg = Package.getPackage(" my.package.version1.class1");
```

can you please assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.lang.Class.forName(fullClassPackage)`.

Example,

```
  val versionParamater = "version1"
  val fullPackage = "my.package."+versionParamater+".class1"
  val versionedClass = Class.forName(fullPackage)
  assert(versionedClass.getSimpleName == "class1")
  assert(versionedClass.getPackage.getName == "my.package.version1")
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to revert to the `java.lang.Class.forName` method to get hold of the class. But note that you will get back a `Class<?>` rather than a `Class<class1>`. For example:

```
scala> Class.forName("java.lang.String")
res0: Class[_] = class java.lang.String
```

You can cast it, though:

```
scala> res0.asInstanceOf[Class[String]]
res1: Class[String] = class java.lang.String
```

A mis-cast will *not* result in a `ClassCastException`:

```
scala> res0.asInstanceOf[Class[Integer]]
res2: Class[Integer] = class java.lang.String
```